# Prometheus query in Grafana with query variable

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

My Grafana panel query is

```
sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{node=~"$workers"}) / sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores{node=~"$workers"})
```

The variable of "workers" is defined as a Prometheus query variable

```
label_values(kube_node_role{role="worker"}, node)
```

[image]
This query will return a list of nodes that have the label of `role="worker"`.

<strike>The question is because there might be a situation where one of the nodes doesn't contain any pod that defines CPU limits, so the metric of `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores` won't contain that host.</strike>

<strike>When using `{node=~"$workers"}` in the panel, the whole query will return `N/A` because `sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{node=~"$workers"})` return `N/A`.</strike>

I found out that the reason is when referring the variable `$workers`, it only pick up the first host, and coincidentally the first host doesn't have the metric of `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores`, so in the panel, it shows `N/A`.
[image]

[image]

How can I fix it or improve the query to get only workers CPU limits committment? Anything wrong to my set up?

PS: I try to define a new constant variable named with `hosts` that has all the nodes which return by the query of `label_values(kube_node_role{role="worker"}, node)`, but manually combine them with `|`(the constant variable looks like `hostA|hostB|hostC`). By adjusting the query with using this variable `sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{node=~"$hosts"}) / sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores{node=~"$hosts"})`, it could display correctly!
Could it might be the Grafana inside mechannism problem that when using multi values from a query variable?

**Debug screenshots**
The first query only contains one host.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dashboard setting, choose the variable options as

```
Hide               = empty
Multi-value        = enable
Include All option = enable
```

Then select "all" from the dashboard label, so the query "node=~${workers}" could select all nodes that are filtered out by the query variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack:

`sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{node=~"$workers"} or kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores{node=~"$workers"}*0) / sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores{node=~"$workers"})`

you can easily join `node` label values in `kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores` by doing `sum(a or b*0)`. By doing so, when you do query with host doesn't exist in `a` but exist in `b`, you will get a `0`

An additional screenshoot to clear my point.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
However, in my query, the molecular could be ```N/A``` but the denominator never(because ```kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores``` always have metric values).

Comment: True, that's why you need denominator to play a trivial (or let's say a factor that always equals to 0 in the sum aggregation) role in molecular, then your molecular will be a constructed `0` instead of N/A when a query can't hit any  `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores` metric.

Comment: @mayer Hum, I just realized that I might have misunderstand your question. Frankly, I'm not sure if I understand it now. If you check `query inspector` in grafana, you will find that it generates the query filter the same as yours, just like `hostA|hostB|hostC`. They shouldn't have a different behavior

Comment: Hi, I checked the ```query inspector```, but it looks like the variable of ```$workers``` doesn't equal to my constant variable ``hostA|hostB|hostC`, it only contains one host ```sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores{node=~"de1tst-78j9w-infra-46r7f"})```(de1tst-78j9w-infra-46r7f is one host returned by the query variable)

Comment: "it only contains one host". If that's not what you expected, then I think it's a good start for debugging. Check if `label_values(kube_node_role{role="worker"}, node)` returns three elements, or if $node has been picked a value accidentally

Comment: I can see the ```label_values(kube_node_role{role="worker"}, node)``` returns many hosts as expected in "Preview of values".
I can put a screenshot to the question so you can get it.